# Netty StreamCorruptedException After Keyexchange

Tags: java, exception, networking, encryption, netty

I am trying to build an encrypted Netty connection using AES.
RSA is helping me to transmit the AES key and the iv.

Server and client have the same key and iv after the exchange. I am creating ciphers to
actually de- and encrypt stuff with it.
When I am running the server on my pc in eclipse with the Cp1252 encoding it's working fine.
As soon as I change the encoding to UTF-8 (encoding my client is written in) or run the server on my Linux system its not working anymore.

I saw that i can get the iv from the cipher with `cipher.getIV();` unfortunately they're not the same
so that might be the problem.

[Exception (client)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCjPs.png)

[Server output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWHhp.png)

As you can see the AES key and IV are the same.

This is how I'm generating the Cipher

```
public static Cipher generateCipher(byte[] secret, int mode, byte[] iv) {
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(new String(secret).toCharArray(), iv, 65536, 128);
        try {
            byte[] key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1").generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB8/NoPadding");
            IvParameterSpec parameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(secretKey.getEncoded());

            cipher.init(mode, secretKey, parameterSpec);
            return cipher;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

This is how I print the Strings

```
byte[] aesKey = CryptionUtils.decryptRSA(packet.getKey(), rsaKeys.getPrivate());
byte[] iv = CryptionUtils.decryptRSA(packet.getIv(), rsaKeys.getPrivate());

if (iv.length != 12 || aesKey.length != 16) {
        server.sendPacket(ip, new KickPacket(EnumKickPacket.INVALID_AES_INFO.ordinal()));
        server.disconnectClient(ip, EnumKickPacket.INVALID_AES_INFO.name());
}

Cipher decryptCipher = CryptionUtils.generateCipher(aesKey, Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, iv);
Cipher encryptCipher = CryptionUtils.generateCipher(aesKey, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, iv);

System.out.println("IV: " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(iv));
System.out.println("AESKey: " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(aesKey));
System.out.println("DecryptCipher: " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(decryptCipher.getIV()));
System.out.println("EncryptCipher: " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptCipher.getIV()));
```

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including sample data so that a repro is possible. Test data in a screenshot is not helpful. You are instantiating a string without specifying the charset (`new String(secret)`). This can result in using the platform's default charset, which can vary cross-platform and cause the issue. Also strange are an IV in the KDF (instead of a salt) and using the key as an IV (instead of a random or KDF generated IV). By the way, IV and salt are generally no secret and need not be encrypted.

Comment: Thanks helped a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new String(secret, Charset.forName("UTF-8")`
Fixed the issue.